# WP_Error Object in wp_remote_post & wp_remote_get

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, wordpress-rest-api, php-curl

I am using localhost and working on a wordpress plugin, I try to get and post data with wp_remote_get and wp_remote_post, I also set all wp remote get and post args, but I got WP ERROR, cURL error 28.

1-Dashboardfile

```
$endpoint = add_query_arg(
        array(
            'code' => $purchase,
        ),
        self::$api
);

$options = [
        'body'        => wp_json_encode( array(
            'code' => $purchase,
        ) ),
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'headers'     => [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ],
        'timeout'     => 10,
        'redirection' => 5,
        'blocking'    => true,
        'httpversion' => '1.0',
        'sslverify'   => false,
];

$remote_test = wp_remote_post( $endpoint, $options );
```

2-Verificationfile

```
$baseUrl = get_site_url(); 
$args = array(
    'timeout' => 10,
    "sslverify" => false,
);

$licenses_url = $baseUrl . '/wp-json/lmfwc/v2/licenses?consumer_key=ck_a50c1db92c5e5aa63d4&consumer_secret=cs_2b3e19c';
$response = wp_remote_get( $licenses_url, $args );
```

Error

```
WP_Error Object
(
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [http_request_failed] => Array
                (
                    [0] => cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 10001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
                )
        )

    [error_data] => Array
        (
        )

    [additional_data:protected] => Array
        (
        )
)
```

Comment: `lmfwc` is the License Manager for WooCommerce plugin. Do you have it installed?

Comment: yes, i installed lmfwc and i create a rest-api-key, as you can see i used consumer key and consumer secret in url, to get licenses